# Python pandas editing multiple rows

Tags: python, pandas

Hi here's my [database](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dHlcf.png)

and I want to change Player rows so I'm left only with Player first name and surname and get rid of \initials. For example Instead of Nikola Jokić\jokicni01 I need Nikola Jokić only.

Comment: welcome to SO, please provide a [mcve] and take some time to read [ask] and [tour] images are not considered reproducible as one cannot paste it into their IDE to replicate your dataset/issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use **[`str.split()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.split.html)** and grab the first part of the list:

```
import pandas as pd

df['Player'] =df['Player'].str.split('\\').str[0]
```

Or with **[`pd.assign`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.assign.html)**

```
df = df.assign(Player = df.Player.str.split('\\').str[0])
```

Initial DF:

```
                            Player Pos
0          Nikola Jokic\jokicni01   C
1  Giannis Antetokounmpo\antegi01  PF
2         Stephen Curry\curryst01  PG
```

Resulting DF:

```
                  Player Pos
0           Nikola Jokic   C
1  Giannis Antetokounmpo  PF
2          Stephen Curry  PG
```